# Upgrade to another version

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Can I upgrade my SuiteCRM instance to any version or I must respect the order of upgrades, for example to upgrade from 7.4.3 to 7.7.9
Do I have to upgrade first from 7.4.3 to 7.6.10 then from 7.6.10 to 7.7.9 or I can upgrade directly from 7.4.3 to 7.7.9 ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  [SuiteCRM Downloads](https://suitecrm.com/download) page has a list of upgrade version options, currently this lists:

- SuiteCRM-Upgrade-7.8.x-to-7.8.3
- SuiteCRM-Upgrade-7.7.x-to-7.8.3
- SuiteCRM-Upgrade-7.6.x-to-7.8.3

If your on a version previous to any of those listed, you will need to upgrade to one of the previous upgrade packs also listed, then upgrade from there to current.

So for example you want to go from 7.2 to 7.8.3, you will need follow the following upgrade process:

1. SuiteCRM-Upgrade-7.2.x-to-7.3.2
2. SuiteCRM-Upgrade-7.3.x-to-7.4.4
3. SuiteCRM-Upgrade-7.4.x-to-7.6.10
4. SuiteCRM-Upgrade-7.6.x-to-7.8.3